# python variable contains three lists not one

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm writing a program in Python to read a file and turn the file into **a** **list** of words. At the moment it gives me four lists (one for each line of the file) The function `rstrip()` doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure why.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fread = open(fname)

for line in fread:
    line = line.rstrip()
    lst = line.split()
    print lst
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to speculate that you want to join the lists from each line. You can do this with [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
lst = []
for line in fread:
    line = line.rstrip()
    lst.extend(line.split())

print lst
```

Another way of doing this might be

```
lst = fread.read().strip().split()
```

Also, in either case, don't forget to close your file.

```
fread.close()
```

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thank you. I don't understand why the rstrip()function wouldn't have taken out the separate lines though

Comment: @user3553851, Each time you go through the loop, you only have access to one line of the file. `rstrip()` just removes newlines but doesn't change the fact that you only have one line.